# Is using fs::rename to move files between different file systems atomic?

Tags: file, rust, filesystems

On Linux, if we move (rename) a file from one file system to another like this:

```
fs::rename("/src/a", "/dest/a")?;
```

is it possible the file `/dest/a` to become visible/available to other potential readers (processes that scan `/dest/` for example) *before* the whole file data (contents) is fully copied to the destination file system?

Comment: The thing `mv` does under-the-hood when the underlying syscall fails because the source and destination are on two different filesystems is what you need to do here: Create a temporary file on the destination filesystem, copy content into it, and then use `fs::rename` to atomically rename that temporary file to the destination name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot! I was wondering about how `mv` works, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html)

> This will not work if the new name is on a different mount point.

So you shouldn't be using `fs::rename` to move between mount points. It's a simple filesystem rename and is not actually *moving* any data (which is why you can `fs::rename` a 2-terabyte file fairly quickly), so it only works if the source and destination are on the same filesystem.

If the source and destination *are* on the same mount point, then the answer is no. It's not possible for someone to read it before it's fully available, since, again, no data is actually transferred: it's just a single operation of "this pointer now points here and this one doesn't exist anymore".

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I saw that restriction in the docs. So I guess Rust doesn't have a `move()` function and I should sequentially copy and delete?